# Python read particular cell value

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file and I want to read particular cell one by one using Python, and that value of cell I am going to use as one message to send to ECU (Electronic control Unit).

Could anyone please give me some idea? I have two colums for example as i have given below:

```
Request**                Response**
Client -> Server         Server -> Client

10 01                    50 01
10 81                    expected no answer

10 02                    50 02
10 01                    50 01
10 82                    expected no answer

10 03                    50 03
10 83                    expected no answer     

10 04                  7F 10 12
10 00                  7F 10 12
10 84                  7F 10 12
10 FF                  7F 10 12
10 01 00               7F 10 13
10                     7F 10 13
```

Comment: Welcome! You will increase your chances on good answer by providing links, e.g. to a doc of ECU, and by improving the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe [this](http://www.python-excel.org/) will help you parsing the excel file. Your code could look like this when you use this librabry:

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("/path/to/your/file.xls")
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

particular_cell_value = first_sheet.cell(12,34).value
# to something with this
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply but i am not able to import xlrd module,

Comment: @user2750946 you first need to download and install the module, [e.g. from here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)